# MariaDB reporing unsafe statement due to multiple keys on table with only one key

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB server: 5.5.68 on CentOS 7.

My mariadb.log file is filling up with huge numbers of errors all of this form (with only sourceID value varying):

`[Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO sourcesToAnalyse (sourceID, analysed) VALUES ('97984', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE analysed=0`

Which seems clear enough -- except that `sourcesToAnalyse` does not have multiple keys:

```
> show create table sourcesToAnalyse;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sourcesToAnalyse | CREATE TABLE `sourcesToAnalyse` (
  `sourceID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `analysed` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sourceID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sourceID` (`sourceID`),
  CONSTRAINT `sourcesToAnalyse_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sourceID`) REFERENCES `sources` (`sourceID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

So, why I am seeing this error? Does it point to a configuration issue somewhere? As far as I can see, I am simply doing an insert on a table with a single key, so the error message is wrong. Is it because the key in question is a foreign key in another table? Or is it telling me that I should schedule some downtime, and update to a newer version of the mariadb server?

I know how to workaround the problem (set binary log format to mixed, or presumably using "replace into" instead if "insert/on duplicate"), but I'd like to know if the existence of this problem is pointing to some deeper issue that I cannot fathom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove ```UNIQUE KEY `sourceID` (`sourceID`)``` - it is complete duplicate of PK and hence it is obviously excess.

Comment: Is that not just a mariaDB quirk in how it shows "create table"? I actually created with `CREATE TABLE sourcesToAnalyse (sourceID bigint unsigned not null unique primary key ...`; do you mean that I should not give "Unique" as well as PK in that create statement?

Comment: Primary key is unique key. So one more unique key is excess. PS. Your table looks like one created using `SERIAL` datatype alias.

Comment: OK, thanks very much - I didn't register that PK automatically set unique. PS not use SERIAL, I specified that datatype explicitly :)

Comment: PK is (1) index (2) unique index (3) unique index which does not allow NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

Beside (the already mentioned) duplicate key you should upgrade to a more recent version (actual version is 10.7, oldest supported version is 10.2, version 5.5 eoled in 2020).

This issue has been fixed. Since MariaDB 10.0 both replica and source use the same key order (if storage engine is the same).

Comment: Thanks.  Needs some downtime scheduling and upgrading the production server is always a tad scary :S